# Write Queries With Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I have this kind of a stored procedure in the database, how do I implement it with the sequelize ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sarbazi]
    @name nvarchar(255),
    @famili nvarchar(255),
    @grade nvarchar(255)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT
        [dbo].[createProjects].[name], 
        [dbo].[createProjects].family,
        [dbo].[createProjects].grade
    FROM 
        [dbo].[createProjects]
    WHERE
        ([dbo].[createProjects].[name] = @name OR @name = '')
        AND ([dbo].[createProjects].family = @famili OR @famili = '')
        AND ([dbo].[createProjects].grade = @grade OR @grade = '')
END
```

I can not implement that, is it possible to write it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var param = req.body;
        var condition =
            {
                where:
                    {

                    }
            }
        if (param.name ) {
            condition.where.id = param.id
        }
       if (param.famili ) {
            condition.where.famili = param.famili 
        }
       if (param.grade ) {
            condition.where.grade = param.grade 
        }
        Users.findAll(condition).then(function (result) {
            resp.send(result);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```